# How to use wordpress core functions like wpdb functions in secondary file of plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

What I try to do is: I have a database entry (table row with an id as primary key) and I want to delete the row with a click on a button on my plugin's page. There is an ajax call which sends the ID to a file called delete.php in my plugin's directory. The ajax call is working but now I want to use the wpdb function to delete the row in the WP database in my custom table. Because it's just a secondary plugin's script and not the main you can't use these functions by default.

I tried:

```
require_once('wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
```

and then:

```
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix .'my_tablename';

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        var_dump($_POST['id']); 
        var_dump($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'"));
    }

}
```

But it was just causing a network error 500. I also tried `require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-load.php');` - but same error. I tried to figure out what went wrong with `var_dump( get_included_files() );exit;` after the line with `require_once()` but still error 500. What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Try with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wp-load.php'`

Comment: thx, but that didn't work unfortunately. But require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); did. Still thx! :)

Comment: It was typo :) It should be like this :
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/name-of-your-wordpress-folder/wp-load.php'`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. But I think to do it with the relative path is better because I want to use the plugin on several sites ;)

Comment: Great ! Have a good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It was just a path thing:
`require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` worked

Comment: Have you gave physical path ??

Comment: I think the relative link will work in the future too. The plugin's path and the wp-load path haven't changed in years. Or what do you mean?